# Is there a way to get a constant update of the server time from Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

My goal is for the app's `viewController` to do something when it reaches `6:00 pm` server time. The problem is that if I use the generic code:

```
let timestamp = FIRServerValue.timestamp(),
```

Then it only gets called once, and I can't see the data updated to check against `6:00`. Any solutions or workarounds would be very helpful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get the timestamp, compare it to the difference of your current computer. So for instance if you get it at it's 4:01 but your current computer is 4:00 then you know you have +1 minutes.

Then just wait for 6:00 - difference, in this case 1 minute and your server time will read 5:59 but firebase will be +1 therefore it will be 6:00.

Comment: So I probably should of clarified, I'm going to be deploying this to different regions such as China, so I want it to respond to the server time. It should respond to 6:00 pm firebase server time. I believe if I use the local time, glitchy behavior can happen, or the user can change it up.

Comment: That's what I'm suggesting... each server would just track it's offset from the firebase time.

Comment: I think I read your comment to quickly, I think I get what your saying. Let me try it out. Thanks.